# How long and where Android 10 keeps phone logs

Tags: calls, call-history

I found my phone logs in `com.google.android.dialer/databases/annotated_call_log.db`. It covers only 4 months period. Is there other phone logs in Android 10?

Comment: The Phone app handles it, so it depends on the app, not the device or Android version.

Answer (score 0):

Found it here `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/calllog.db`. At least 18 months history.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).